# Did the grim reaper appear to Kuina before her death, as it did to Zoro?

Tags: one-piece

In *One Piece*, Kuina died after she slipped on the stairs. But I have a theory that she used Wado Ichimojo for her training, which had been draining the Busoshoku Haki from her body, and so the grim reaper would have appeared before her as it did for Zoro.

Is this true? Did the grim reaper appear to Kuina before her death?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it'd have appeared before Kuina, as Zoro had several life-and-death situations with the same *Wado Ichimonji*, including the fights with Mihawk and Arlong in East Blue, and the Grim Reaper didn't appear before him anytime.

It's more likely that the Grim Reaper was the soul/will of *Enma*, as it'd have been stated in anime and manga that cursed swords have a will of their own, and *Enma* was made to siphon a person's conqueror's haki at a higher scale compared to other swords like *Wado Ichimonji* and *Kitetsu* swords.

Therefore, it was most likely the manifestation of Enma.